# How can I ensure I'm protected by the "Safe Harbor" clause?

Tags: content, legal, terms-of-use

I run a site that allows users to provide their own content & have it publicly available.  I've got a standard privacy policy but am wondering what measures I should take to ensure I'm covered by the Safe Harbor clause in the DMCA.

Do I need a terms & conditions page?  Does it need to be linked / quoted on the publishing pages?  Do I just need to ensure I respond to any DMCA notices that come in?

Answer (score 3):

[In order to qualify for safe harbor protection](http://www.chillingeffects.org/dmca512/), a service provider who hosts content must:

- have no knowledge of, or financial benefit from, infringing activity on its network
- have a copyright policy and provide proper notification of that policy to its subscribers
- list an agent to deal with copyright complaints

That page also has a link to an extensive FAQ.